# Is this a violation of the Law of Demeter?

Tags: law-of-demeter

Is this a violation of the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)?

```
private void MoveEmptyCells()
{
     IEnumerable<Cell> cells = this.internalGrid.GetAllEmptyCells();
     foreach(Cell cell in cells)
     {
          cell.RowIndex += this.moveDistance; // violation here?
     }
}
```

How about this one?

```
private void MoveEmptyCell()
{
     Cell cell = this.internalGrid.GetEmptyCell();
     cell.RowIndex += this.moveDistance; // violation here?         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) says:

> More formally, the Law of Demeter for functions requires that a method
>   m of an object O may only invoke the methods of the following kinds of
>   objects:
>
> O itself
>  m's parameters
>  Any objects created/instantiated
>   within m
>  O's direct component objects
>  A global variable,
>   accessible by O, in the scope of m
>
> (...) That is, the code a.b.Method() breaks the law where
>   a.Method() does not.

```
Cell cell = this.internalGrid.GetEmptyCell(); // is O's direct component Object
cell.RowIndex += this.moveDistance; // Cell is a object created/instantiated within m
```

***this.moveDistance;*** // Method of // O itself.
Return a RowIndex object with no behavior, and so Demeter does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

It is if not breaking, then it is slightly bending the Demeter Law.

You could try implementing it in a way so that you can call:

```
(...)
this.internalGrid.MoveEmptyCellBy(this.moveDistance);
(...)
```